Alternative approach for $\int \frac{e^{\cos^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1}(x)\right)}} \, dx$
Exponential Substitution can be seen as an extension of using Euler's formula to directly integrate irrational functions and is especially efficient for integrals of the form:
$$\int f\left(x, \tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1} \frac{x+b}{a}\right), \tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \sec^{-1} \frac{x+b}{a}\right)\right) \, dx.\tag{1}$$
By using the real or imaginary part of Euler's formula, we can also find the antiderivatives of integrals such as:
$$\int \frac{x+b}{a} \cdot e^{\cos^{-1} \frac{x+b}{a}} \, dx\tag{2}$$
and
$$\int \sqrt{(x+b)^2 - a^2} \cdot e^{\cos^{-1} \frac{x+b}{a}} \, dx,\tag{3}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $a>0$. For example, let's evaluate
$$\int xe^{\cos^{-1}(x)}\,dx.\tag{4}$$
By transforming the integral according to formula $(23)$ in this blog post and using the real part of Euler's formula, we have
$$\begin{aligned}\int xe^{\cos^{-1}(x)}\,dx&=\text{Re}\left[-\frac{i}{2}\int e^{i\alpha}e^{\alpha}\left(e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}\right)\,d\alpha\right]\\&=\text{Re}\left[-\frac{i}{2}\int \left(e^{\alpha}-e^{(1+2i)\alpha}\right)\,d\alpha\right]\\&=\text{Re}\left[-\frac{i}{2}\left(e^{\alpha}-\frac{e^{(1+2i)\alpha}}{1+2i}\right)+C\right]\\&=\frac{1}{10} e^{\alpha} \left( 2 \cos(2\alpha) - \sin(2\alpha) \right)+C\\&=\frac{1}{10} e^{\cos^{-1}(x)} \left( 2 \cos(2\cos^{-1}(x)) - \sin(2\cos^{-1}(x)) \right)+C\\&=-\frac{e^{\cos^{-1}(x)}}{5} \left(x \sqrt{1 - x^2} - 2x^2 + 1 \right)+C \end{aligned}$$
Of course, you can also let $u = \cos^{-1}(x)$ and then integrate by parts. Not sure what might be easier in this case, but when evaluating the integral
$$\int \frac{e^{\cos^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1}(x)\right)}} \, dx\tag{5}$$
Wolfram Alpha cannot solve it. WA cannot solve it even after the simplification $\tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1}(x)\right)=x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$:
$$\int \frac{e^{\cos^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt{x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}} \, dx\tag{6}$$
However, using exponential substitution, $(5)$ becomes
$$\int \frac{e^{\cos^{-1}(x)}}{\sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1}(x)\right)}} \, dx=-\frac{i}{2}\int e^{(1-\frac{i}{2})\alpha}\left(e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha}\right)\,d\alpha, $$
which is not hard to integrate. So this is my question:
How do you integrate $(5)$ without resorting to Euler's formula? Is it still possible using IBP?

Is there any particular reason you want to avoid the Euler's formula when it seems to solve the integral?

The routine substitution $t=\cos^{-1}x$ would reduce it to
$$\int \frac{e^{\cos^{-1}x}}{\sqrt{x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}} , dx = -\int e^{(1+\frac i2)t}\sin t\ dt$$

@Quanto: But you've used Euler's formula to reduce it, haven't you? My question is whether it can be solved without resorting to Euler's formula.

@AmrutAyan: I am particularly interested in exploring the advantages of exponential substitution (ES) over traditional methods. For certain classes of integrals, it seems that ES is indeed more efficient.

Isn't it kind of hard to avoid exponentials when you literally have $e$ to the power of something in the integrand?
